# IIS Url rewrite with regex redirect to wrong destination

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I must do a redirect using a regex...

I must do the following redirects:

```
www.mysite.com/old-category/old-subcategory           -> www.mysite.com/new-category/new-subcategory
www.mysite.com/old-category/old-subcategory/old-page1 -> www.mysite.com/new-category/new-subcategory/new-page1
www.mysite.com/old-category/old-subcategory/old-page2 -> www.mysite.com/new-category/new-subcategory/new-page2
...
www.mysite.com/old-category/old-subcategory/old-pageN -> www.mysite.com/new-category/new-subcategory/new-pageN
```

where `new-pageN` can be a randow word...

Here my rule in the web.config:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        ...
        <rule name="myCustomRule">
           <match url="^old-category/old-subcategory/(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
           <action type="Redirect" url="new-category/new-subcategory/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

The problem is that when I write `www.mysite.com/old-category/old-subcategory/old-page1`  in my browser, It is redirect to `www.mysite.com/new-category/new-subcategory/n`. It takes just the first letter of the last segment of the old url.

I do not understand what is wrong... everything look like correct to me..
I have also tried with

```
^old-category/old-subcategory/(.+)
^old-category/old-subcategory/(\w+)
^old-category/old-subcategory/([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)
^old-category/old-subcategory/(\b\w+\b)
```

Nothing works... What's wrong?

Thank you

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: The rule can work in my test.https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMc0L.png To facilitate the observation of the rewriting process, I changed the redirect to rewrite, but the results of the two are the same. Please follow lexli's document to check in fail request tracing. Don't forget to change redirect to rewrite so that can record the entire rewriting process.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not much clear...
By the way

1. Try to escape the "/"  `<match url="^old-category\/old-subcategory\/(.*)"` ignoreCase="false" />
2. I think that redirect should be:

   ```
   <action type="Redirect" url="/new-category/new-subcategory/{R:1}" />
   ```

   or

   ```
   <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/new-category/new-subcategory/{R:1}" />
   ```